# My user profile update view (class based view) returns a 404

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a UserProfile model that I want to let people update if they wish to.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView

class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "preferences.html"
    success_url = "/profile/"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from profiles import views
from profiles.views import UserProfileCreateView, UserProfileUpdateView

urlpatterns = [url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)$/edit', UserProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),]
```

Now my problem is that when I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/someusername/edit I get a 404. I don't understand exactly what's happening with the pk in the urlpatterns. What url pattern should I use to see the page where I can update the profile? Or is there something wrong here?

I

Comment: Also, your URL pattern is expecting an id, and it looks like you are sending a username, which would not work. Change the regex pattern to accept characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `$` in the middle of your regex, which makes no sense because that is the terminator character. Remove it.

Comment: Or even better, move it to the end of the regex: `^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$`

Comment: Thanks very much, it was a combination of both the regex and what @karthikr said.